# AWS RDS Aurora Query Editor : Access denied for user 'admin'@'#.#.#.#' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am trying out the query editor and running the default query :

`select * from information_schema.tables; # Press run and see the current database tables below`

gives me this error : Access denied for user 'admin'@'#.#.#.#' (using password: YES)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`` GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO 'admin'@#.#.#.#; ``

The above command solved it. Referenced from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/961301/cant-create-a-new-user-with-all-privileges-on-aws-rds-mysql-instance).

Comment: It doesn't solve for my case. An by definition, how can admin user grant access to itself if it is not connecting properly?

Comment: Surprisingly, this worked for me a few times now.